# Python multi-level imports is not working

Tags: python, python-import

Consider this folder structure

```
│   main.py
│
+---src
│   +---functions
│   │   │   hello.py
│   │       
│   +---models
│       │   hello_model.py
```

main.py

```py
from src.functions.hello import http_message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(http_message("This is a test message").message)
```

hello.py

```py
from models.hello_model import HttpMessageModel


def http_message(message: str) -> HttpMessageModel:
    return HttpMessageModel(
        message=message,
        code=200,
    )
```

hello_model.py

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class HttpMessageModel:
    message: str
    code: int
```

If I launch `py main.py` I get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.functions.hello import http_message
  File "L:\wamp64\www\GITHUB\create-python-app\src\functions\hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.hello_model import HttpMessageModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models
```

In this particular case how do I handle imports (with namespaces ?)

full code exemple : https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/create-python-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to the problem is posted here (as a Pull Request), you are free to accept it:

> [create-python-app-PR](https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/create-python-app/pull/1)

The main issue is that you are not adding `src.` module on the route of your module `src/functions/hello.py`.

Before:

```
from models.hello_model import HttpMessageModel
```

After:

```
from src.models.hello_model import HttpMessageModel
```

Also, after run the main.py (in my case using python3 main.py) I got this output:

```
hello world !
4
This is a test message
```

Also, the tests (2 in total), ends correctly, I didn't try the coverage tests.

Comment: Also the Pull Request contains a recommendation about importing modules along Python projects. In here [Python3 - Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), you can understand the reason of creating __init__.py files.

Answer (score 0):

Your hello.py is in functions folder, just add ".." in your hello.py as:

`from ..models.hello_model import HttpMessageModel`

It will pull the execution scope out from **function** folder while executing import in hello.py, thus your intended import in hello.py will work fine. I just tried it, and I can see the output.

PS: I am Ubuntu 20.04 user.